# Error while inserting multiple rows in greenDAO database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I'm trying to insert a multiple rows at a time.

The table is as shown below,

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "options")
public class Option {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("option_text")
    @Property(nameInDb = "option_text")
    private String optionText;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("question_id")
    @Property(nameInDb = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("is_correct")
    @Property(nameInDb = "is_correct")
    private boolean isCorrect;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Property(nameInDb = "created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Property(nameInDb = "updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;

    @Generated(hash = 435722130)
    public Option(Long id, String optionText, Long questionId, boolean isCorrect,
                  String createdAt, String updatedAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.optionText = optionText;
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Generated(hash = 104107376)
    public Option() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOptionText() {
        return optionText;
    }

    public void setOptionText(String optionText) {
        this.optionText = optionText;
    }

    public Long getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Long questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return isCorrect;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        isCorrect = correct;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public boolean getIsCorrect() {
        return this.isCorrect;
    }

    public void setIsCorrect(boolean isCorrect) {
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
    }
}
```

And insert function

```
public Observable<Boolean> saveOptionList(final List<Option> optionList) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                mDaoSession.getOptionDao().insertInTx(optionList);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Here option list contains all the fields except "id" which will auto-increment. So I'm passing null in the place of id.

But I'm getting unique constraint failed exception. If I pass only one item, the insertion is successful.

How can I insert multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Option class like below code.

```
@Entity(
        indexes = {
                @Index(value = "id", unique = true)
        }
)
public class Option {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Property(nameInDb = "option_text")
    private String optionText;

    @Property(nameInDb = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;

    @Property(nameInDb = "is_correct")
    private boolean isCorrect;

    @Property(nameInDb = "created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    @Property(nameInDb = "updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;

    public Option(String optionText, Long questionId, boolean isCorrect,
                  String createdAt, String updatedAt) {
        this.optionText = optionText;
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Option() {
    }

    @Generated(hash = 435722130)
    public Option(Long id, String optionText, Long questionId, boolean isCorrect,
            String createdAt, String updatedAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.optionText = optionText;
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getOptionText() {
        return optionText;
    }

    public void setOptionText(String optionText) {
        this.optionText = optionText;
    }

    public Long getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Long questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return isCorrect;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        isCorrect = correct;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public boolean getIsCorrect() {
        return this.isCorrect;
    }

    public void setIsCorrect(boolean isCorrect) {
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and insert data like below.

```
  mDaoSession.getOptionDao().insert(new Option("anyText", 3L, true, "yesterday", "today"));
```

Id will be incremented automatically.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Pankaj thanks for the reply. If I use the insert() for inserting multiple rows, it will take more time. I need to insert all the rows in a single transaction so I have to use insertTx(). If I insert one by one using insert() it will insert without error but how can I insert using a single transaction.

Comment: @Praveen Please try this:

if (mDaoSession.getOptionDao().loadAll().size() != 0) {
                    int size = optionList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        mDaoSession.getOptionDao().insert(optionList.get(i));
                    }
                }

it will add all data to the database.

Comment: Pankaj I'm able to insert data one by one which consumes more time, if we can insert in a single transaction it will take almost 500% lesser time. So we need to use insertTx(). I agree your solution will work, but I need the optimized way of inserting.

Comment: @Praveen then you can create a method and call it when the application starts, you can set a boolean in shared preference to check if the application starts for the first time or not.


    private void insertDataIntoDb() {
        mDaoSession.getOptionDao().insertInTx(optionArrayList);

    }

Comment: Pankaj here I'm getting a unique constraint exception for the column "id"

Comment: @Praveen for unique constraint exception you can make your option class like I showed you in my first post and then try. I am sure it will work.

Comment: Yes @Pankaj, your first solution will work which consumes time, I need to use the insertTx() which intended to insert multiple rows which consumes 500% lesser time.

Comment: @Praveen Use option class only from the first solution and then you can create a method and call it when the application starts, you can set a boolean in shared preference to check if the application starts for the first time or not. private void insertDataIntoDb() { mDaoSession.getOptionDao().insertInTx(optionArrayList); }

Comment: I'll try it out, but why I have to call it while starting the application

Comment: @Praveen it's not compulsory to call it when the application starts, you can call it anytime and anywhere throughout your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pankaj, I'll try it out and get update the result to u

Comment: @Praveen Sure, no issues.

Comment: Pankaj, please check my answer, we can use the above code for inserting multiple rows at a time, the issue was I was inserting the redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I was inserting the list of objects with same data, I mean to say I was inserting the redundant objects so it was throwing the error. We can't insert redundant data hence the issue is solved.